# Bcrypt password compare fails when login

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, mongoose-schema, restful-authentication

when I am trying to login with the defined url , at a point of bcrypting compare password it fails.

**login route:-**

```
router.post('/:compId/administration/login' , (req, res, next) => {

    Admin.find({'admins.email': req.body.email},{ companyID: req.params.compId })
    .exec()
    .then(admin => {
        if(admin.admins.length < 1) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: "Auth failed. admin not found."
            })
        }
        bcryptt.compare(req.body.password, admin.admins.password, (err, result) =>{
            if (err) {
                return res.json({
                message: "Auth failed. Check email and password"
                });             
            }                   
            if (result && admin.admins.verified === "true"){
                const adminEmaill = "xyz@info.com";
                const role2 = admin.admins.email===adminEmaill? "superadmin" : "admin";
                const token = jwt.sign( 
                    {
                        email: admin.admins.email,
                        phoneNo: admin.admins.phoneNumber,
                        role2,
                        comID: admin.admins.companyID
                    },
                    process.env.JWT_KEY,
                    {
                        expiresIn : "1h"
                    });
                    return res.status(200).json({
                    message: "Auth Successful",
                    token : token
                    }); 
            }
            else{
                console.log("admin is not verified");   
                return res.json({
                message: "Admin is not verified"
                }); 
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        if (err.code == 500)
                    res.status(500).send(["Something went wrong in login"]);
            else
            return next(err);
    }); 
});
```

On response it is not validating my user and throwing `message: "Auth failed. Check email and password"` in response.

I think I have some error in defining my password path.

**My model:-**

```
var adminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    companyName : {
                type: String,
                required: "Company  name can't be empty.",
                required: false
                },  
    companyID:  {
                type: String,
                },              
    admins:     {
                        email :     {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Email can't be empty.",
                                    unique: true
                                    },
                        password:   {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Password name can't be empty."
                                    },
                        firstName : {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "First name can't be empty."
                                    },
                        lastName : {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Last name can't be empty."
                                    },  
                        phoneNumber :   {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Reqired for further contact. Can't be empty."
                                    },
                        verified: String,                               
                        role: String,
                        emailResetTokenn: String,
                        saltSecret: String,
                        users:[ userSchema ]    
    }           
});


adminSchema.pre('save', function (next){
    bcryptt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcryptt.hash(this.admins.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            this.admins.password = hash ;
            this.admins.saltSecret = salt;
            next();
        });
    });
});
```

***I am not getting why I am getting this ? Is defining of  my password is correct ? How can I do this when I have password in nested object ?***

Comment: When it returns error, it is an error existed not mismatching. So check the `err`

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani How can I check my error ? Is my above code correct in terms of nested schema ?

Comment: use `console.log()` or debugger libs. Your schema seems correct

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani I am getting `Illegal arguments: string, undefined` in my console

Comment: So check (log) the two arguments you give to `compare` method

Comment: I am getting password in my as `"password": "$2a$10$O0GHxmb0Cad8RQS22F6Ufu/JhySr6hpxvqL3isAitQ35qLALn569K"` in my response registraton

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193925/discussion-between-ebrahim-pasbani-and-noobcoder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `findOne` method on mongoose model.

```
 Admin.findOne({'admins.email': req.body.email, companyID: req.params.compId}) ...
```

The result of `find` method is an array